# Array.some() and Array.every() - how to search for an element?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript

The examples in [the Adobe Array doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html) are not very intuitive...

If I have a `Card` object with properties `str` and `visible`, how do I rewrite this piece of code looking for a visible card with the certain `str` value?

```
FOUND:
for each (var str:String in newHand) {
    for each (card in hand) {
        if (card.visible && str == card.str)
            continue FOUND;
    }

    // there is a new card - redraw the whole hand
    redrawHand(owner);
    break;
}
```

Comment: `.some` and `.every` are not for finding elements, they are for testing a set of elements.

Comment: That's exactly what I need in my code: I'd like to see, if my array `hand` contains any `Card` with the condition `(card.visible && str == card.str)` being true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `some()`, `every()` (and `forEach()`) methods of the `Array` class have two parameters:

- `callback` a function that is executed on each item, it should return true or false based on your criteria
- `thisObject` is an optional object you can supply to the callback function, inside the function you can refer to the object with the `this` keyword. You can form a closure with the callback function if you omit this parameter.

The signature of the callback function is as follows:

```
private var callback:Function = function(currentItem:Object, currentIndex:int, theEntireArray:Array):Boolean
{
    // your logic here returns true/false based on your critera
}
```

For your scenario, perhaps you could use the `some()` method like this:

```
private var comparisonString:String;

private function showTheExampleCode()
{
    for each (var str:String in newHand)
    {
        // comparisonString will be used in the closure
        // maybe you can just use str in the closure instead?
        comparisonString=str;
        if (hand.some(callback))
        {
            // at least one match was found, do something
        }
    } 
}

private var callback:Function(currentItem:Object, currentIndex:int, array:Array):Boolean
{
    // current item is a Card object (you probably do not have to cast it)
    return Card(currentItem).visible && Card(currentItem).str == comparisonString;
}
```

Comment: A quick note about the second param `thisObject`: it is only applicable to unbound functions, not bound methods.